# Laravel: Throwable not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, throwable

I added this snippet to my code:

```
$billingAddress = PartnerAddress::where([
                            ['partner_id' => $partner->id],
                            ['address_type' => 1],
                            ])
                            ->get();
```

And I got:

> (1/1) FatalErrorException
>
> Interface 'Throwable' not found in DriverException.php (line 33)

What can be the error? The log is the same and I didn't found anything based on this error.

Comment: what php version do you use?

Comment: I use 7.1 but also 5.6 is installed, too

Comment: the Throwable interface comes with php7 make sure when you run `php -v`  it's php7 not 5.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing this issue and solved by running "composer dump-autoload".